# How can I get rid of those animation in jquery toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to learn some HTML/CSS/jQuery and decided to make a start page. Everything goes well except for the animation my divs are showing when being toggled. The code is here http://jsfiddle.net/9yz71d3q/. How can I remove them?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".left-span").addClass("inactive");
  $("#s1").addClass("active").removeClass("inactive");
  $(".content").hide();
  $("#c1").show();
}); 

//Whole code to show the first div content and highlight first menu position.
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#s1, #s2, #s3, #s4, #s5").click(function(){ 
    $(".content").hide(240);

    if($(this).is("#s1")) { //Checks which button has been clicked.
           $("#c1").toggle();
    } else if($(this).is("#s2")) {
           $("#c2").toggle();
    } else if($(this).is("#s3")) {
           $("#c3").toggle();
    } else if($(this).is("#s4")) {
           $("#c4").toggle();
    } else if($(this).is("#s5")) {
           $("#c5").toggle();
    } 
    if(!$(this).hasClass("active") ) { //Highlights chosen div.
      $(".left-span").addClass("inactive").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active").removeClass("inactive");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you want to remove the animation, change `$(".content").hide(240);` to `$(".content").hide();`

Comment: Yes, this fixed the problem and can't believe I couldn't catch that.